The behavior of a kind of elliptical integral while one of its parameters turns to infinity.
This integral is developed in the study to 3-dimensional axisymmetric Biot-Savart operator, and could be written as below:
$$K_{3d}(a,b,c,l):=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{l\sqrt{(a+l)^2+(b+l)^2-2(a+l)(b+l)\cos(\theta)}}{((a+l)^2+(b+l)^2-2(a+l)(b+l)\cos(\theta)+c^2)^\frac{3}{2}}\mathrm{d}\theta$$
What could we say about this integral while $l\to\infty$? Apriori, we could expect that this integral converges to the function below up to multiplying some constants.
$$K_{2d}(a,b,c):=\frac{|a-b|}{(a-b)^2+c^2}$$
which is one of the components of the 2-dimensional Biot-Savart kernel.
Any advice is welcomed, thanks in advance!
